# Python 3.X pointing to the wrong framework library?

Tags: installation, python

From the following error message it appears as if Python 3.10 is trying to open a Python 2.7 test file at startup.  Error message:
“File /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/test/test_int.pyo Failed to Decode”

Every time I start up my MacBook (running MacOS 10.15.7) the IDLE opens and I get this error.  This has occurred since installation of Python 3.  Is python 3.10 sharing the same library location as 2.7?  I must have made an improper selection when installing.  Uninstalling and reinstalling python 3.X does not correct the problem.  Any help?

Comment: “I s python 3.10 sharing the same library location as 2.7?” - No; Unless you specifically installed it to the same directory